# Javascript - Adding Days to a Loop

Tags: javascript, loops, date

I have the following

```
       var my_date = '2021-09-27';
        
        my_date = new Date(my_date);
        var new_date = new Date();
        
        for(var i=0; i<10; i++) 
        {
        new_date.setDate(my_date.getDate() + i);
        var this_date = new_date.toISOString();
        console.log(this_date);
        }
```

I was expecting it to output

```
2021-09-27T19:21:26.361Z
2021-09-28T19:21:26.361Z
2021-09-29T19:21:26.361Z
2021-09-30T19:21:26.361Z
2021-10-01T19:21:26.361Z
2021-10-02T19:21:26.361Z
2021-10-03T19:21:26.361Z
2021-10-04T19:21:26.361Z
2021-10-05T19:21:26.361Z
2021-10-06T19:21:26.361Z
```

but for some reason it outputs

```
2021-10-27T19:21:26.361Z
2021-10-28T19:21:26.361Z
2021-10-29T19:21:26.361Z
2021-10-30T19:21:26.361Z
2021-10-31T19:21:26.361Z
2021-11-01T19:21:26.361Z
2021-12-03T19:21:26.361Z
2022-01-03T19:21:26.361Z
2022-02-04T19:21:26.361Z
2022-03-08T19:21:26.361Z
```

As you can see it starts in October not September, and then when it hits the 31st it starts to jump months.

Why is this script behaving like this?

All the examples I have found online seem to suggest this would work.

Thanks

Comment: The setDate() method changes the day of the month of a given Date instance, based on local time.  (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate)

Comment: You could store the date as milliseconds instead and just add on a days worth of milliseconds per iteration.
`new Date(Date.now() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))`

Comment: How about converting to unix epoch time and adding the day represented in milliseconds then converting back? Seems more fullproof to compute it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `setDate` only changes days, so when you create `new Date()` it has current month in it. You have to copy original date to make this works properly.

Here's the fix:

```js
var my_date = '2021-09-27';
        
my_date = new Date(my_date);

        
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) 
{
  // clone date
  var new_date = new Date(my_date.getTime())
  new_date.setDate(my_date.getDate() + i);
  var this_date = new_date.toISOString();
  console.log(this_date);
}
```